# React.js pattern for referencing an object instance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, flux

I have an object that I constantly need to apply/manipulate methods on that looks like this:

```
var asperaWeb = new AW4.Connect({
  sdkLocation: CONNECT_INSTALLER,
  dragDropEnabled: false, 
  minVersion: '3.6.6'
});
```

I have tried placing this object in state so that I can use it within my React component when the user interacts with the UI.

**component state:**

```
function getNavBarState() {
  return {
    asperaWeb: new AW4.Connect({
      sdkLocation: CONNECT_INSTALLER,
      dragDropEnabled: false, 
      minVersion: '3.6.6'
    })
  };
}
```

**JSX in component:**

```
<input 
  className="btn btn-primary" 
  onClick={this.state.asperaWeb.showSelectFileDialog({success:fileControls.uploadFiles})} 
/>
```

But when the component renders, the `input` `onClick` never seems to get set. When I inspect the element with React tools, the `onClick` is `null`.

My questions are:

1. Why is it `null`?
2. Is this the best pattern for keeping an object and applying methods to it? Should it not be in state? Alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

Barring any issues with how you're setting up the component and its state, your issue seems to be that you are actually calling the method `this.state.asperaWeb.showSelectFileDialog` inside the `onClick` attribute. This calls the method as soon as your `input` is mounted and attempts to set `onClick` equal to the returned value from that method.

Instead you should `bind` the method call to `this` context and the value you want passed to it:

```
<input
  className='btn btn-primary' 
  onClick={this.state.asperaWeb.showSelectFileDialog.bind(this, {success:fileControls.uploadFiles})} 
/>
```

It's hard to replicate your specific situation with the information I have, but [here's a working JFiddle with an example](https://jsfiddle.net/bartriordan/bweaetnn/4/) of what I think you're looking for.

(Side note: Facebook recommends against calling `bind` in the `render` since it creates a new function each time it `render`s, but you can easily Google alternative approaches.)